# selectOneMenu Não lista corretamente

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

estou tentando colocar o selectOneMenu em meu código e estou com problemas. Quero listar os meses do ano, ao clicar para selecinar, ele lista os nomes lado a lado e não um em baixo do outro como deve ser.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5" >
    <p:outputLabel for="meses" value="Mês:"/>

        <p:selectOneMenu id="meses" value="#{pesquisaBean.mes}" style="width:150px">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Janeiro" itemValue="0"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Fevereiro" itemValue="1"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Março" itemValue="2"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Abril" itemValue="3"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Maio" itemValue="4"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Junho" itemValue="5"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Julho" itemValue="6"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Agosto" itemValue="7"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Setembro" itemValue="8"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Outubro" itemValue="9"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Novembro" itemValue="10"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dezembro" itemValue="11"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Está usando algum framework CSS ou JavaScript? Pode ser que isto esteja alterando o layout do componente.

Comment: O problema era um css que estava interferido. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Como seu código é com Primefaces, não lembro de ter um `<p:selectOneMenu />` que liste os itens lado a lado.

Lembre-se que a listagem é feita via `<div />` com um `<ul />` com os itens.

O que você deve fazer é aumentar o tamanho da `<div />` e, para cada `<li />`, adicionar a propriedade css `float: left;`

Comment: O problema era um CSS que estava interferindo. muito obrigado pela ajuda.